# How does the slice() function work with the push() function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, slice

Here the output for `a` and `b` is same but in case of slice() we didn't pass any parameter so the output for `a`, `b`, and `c` must be same.  So why is the output of `c` different from `a` and `b` here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p id="1"></p>
        <p id="2"></p>
        <p id="3"></p>
        <p id="4"></p>
        <script>
        var a=["a","b","c"];
        var b=a;
        var c=a.slice();
        a.push("date");
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=a;
        document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=b;
        document.getElementById("3").innerHTML=c;
        document.getElementById("4").innerHTML=a;

        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,date
a,b,c,date
a,b,c
a,b,c,date
```

Comment: You re slicing an original array before push new value into the array which is 'date'

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

So `c` is a copy of `a` whereas `b` is a reference to it.  Thus when you modify `a`, `b` changes but `c` does not.

Answer (score 0):

you are slice your array before pushing a new element. Also slice returns a new array so the reference of "a" array is not impacting your "c" array.

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

`a.slice()` inside the `slice` function not declare any value .so not perform any action.And `a.slice() != a` .Because you are declare the `c=a.slice()` before push into the array. `Slice()` not change array values.Its will duplicate array value pass to the `c` array. If you need ah date just push with array of `c`

```js
var a=["a","b","c"];
        var b=a;
        var c=a.slice();
        a.push("date");
        c.push('date')
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=a;
        document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=b;
        document.getElementById("3").innerHTML=c;
        document.getElementById("4").innerHTML=a;
```

```html
<p id="1"></p>
        <p id="2"></p>
        <p id="3"></p>
        <p id="4"></p>
```